# Test Set Interval with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to test an API that should be called during each interval (10 minutes).  But whenever I run my test suite, I'm getting a timeout error.

My idea was to:

1. Set an initial time

```
jest.useFakeTimers().setSystemTime(new Date('2023-10-11T01:47:32.569703Z'))
```

2. Fast forward the mocked time 10 minutes in advance

```
jest.useFakeTimers().setSystemTime(new Date('2023-10-11T01:57:32.569703Z'))
```

3. Fast forward the timer to catchup

```
jest.advanceTimersByTime(600000); // 10 minutes
```

4. Check to see if the API call had been made

```
expect(apiCall).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Full Code for context:

```
it('calls API when timer expires', async () => {
   jest.useFakeTimers().setSystemTime(new Date('2023-10-11T01:47:32.569703Z'))
   wrapper = shallow(<Component>)
   const apiCall = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'apiCall');
   jest.useFakeTimers().setSystemTime(new Date('2023-10-11T01:57:32.569703Z')) // fast-forward time
   jest.advanceTimersByTime(600000); // 10 minutes
   expect(apiCall).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
   
}
```